# why my code always return integer but if you click on the cells, it shows desired format in the input box under the menu?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using sumif function in a for loop trying to divide every number in a column by 100000000 to adjust for its unit and round the final results to 2 decimal places. VBA always return me integers but if I click on the cells, the disired form appears in the input box under the menu.

I've tried to round the results inside the for loop, it didn't work.

Following is what I have tried,

```
Sub unitchange()
Dim j As Integer
Dim u As Integer
u = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For j = 4 To u
Cells(j, 6) = Round((Cells(j, 6) / 100000000), 2)
Next j
End Sub
```

I expect to have results appear on the worksheet rounded to two decimal places without having to click on it. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use a custom number format?

Comment: Do you mean cells(j,6).numberformat=“#,##0” ? Where should I put it? I tried immediately after “for” and before “next”, didn’t work in both cases.

Comment: Do you perhaps have *text-that-looks-like-a-number*? Also, `Round` behaves slightly differently than `WorksheetFunction.Round`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reset the cell number format at the same time ...

```
Sub unitchange()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim u As Integer
    u = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For j = 4 To u
        Cells(j, 6) = Round((Cells(j, 6) / 100000000), 2)
        Cells(j, 6).NumberFormat = "General"
    Next j
End Sub
```